# Кодировка в c Sharp

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, кодировка, unicode

Не знаю как правильно обозвать данный вопрос) Не пинайте)
Задача стоит получить коды смайлов vk. Но c# упорно съедает сами коды, превращая их в квардраты. Как ему объяснить, что не нужно пихать всякую каку в рот?)

Коды примерно такие:
Пример: 😉 (не забудь точку с запятой в конце)

Выполняю запрос к apiVk и получаю уже квадраты. 
не силен в этих ваших кодировках, подскажите что куда писать, а?)

Comment: е мае. Даже тут код поменялся как надо. А cSharp не хочет

Comment: Опускайся ниже в уровне абстракции понимания _этих наших кодировок_: каждый символ состоит из байт (не знаю как в c#, в java из 2-х байт). Эти байты просто код, число (от 0 до 65+тыс.). Вопрос как отобразить данное число на экране? Есть табличка, зовется UNICODE, где соотносятся эти числа с символами (как раз от 0 до 64000). В этих таблицах есть все символы (вообще все, вот какой не придумаешь, а там уже есть). Но обычно все символы нам не нужны и мы вводим другую табличку, где говорим, что придумаем свои номера для ряда символов (номеров меньше, запомнить легче, пересылать по интернету проще)

Comment: зовется такая новая табличка charset.

Comment: Это что касается кодировок. Есть еще один момент - Шрифт. Что бы нарисовать какой либо символ на экране, нам нужна картинка этого символа (просто зная код символа, даже согласно unicode,мы еще не знаем как его нарисовать). Тут появляется понятие шрифта, который соотносит код (unicoe or charset) с определенным изображением на экране. И если в используемом шрифте отсутствует изображение соотнесенное с определенным кодом символа, то стандартно на экране рисуется какая-либо "кракозябра" или пустой квадрат.

Comment: Так. тогда делаю вывод. Что бы мне получить коды смайлов, мне надо считывать данные не в строку(которая уже имеет какую-то кодировку), а в массив байт. После обрабатывать массив ища в нем байты нужных мне символов. 
Или есть способ по проще?)

Comment: В консоли отображает квадрат, потому как шрифт данный код не поддерживает. А как обрабатывать получаемые байты, каждый решает сам.